# Closing JMX Connection for concurrent operations

Tags: java, multithreading, jmx

I am opening a JMX Connection using `getMBeanServerConnection()` method and then closing it after use in a finally block. And, for a given JMX Connector, 2 successful calls to `getMBeanServerConnection()` usually returns the same `MBeanServerConnection`.

Some of the operations are invoked concurrently, and each of them invokes `getMBeanServerConnection()`. But, they get the SAME connection. And, therefore, when the first operation completes, the remaining operation fails with "Connection Closed" error.

How can I go about resolving this? Should I create multiple connector objects and invoke `getMBeanServerConnection()` on them to retrieve different connections? Or, do I need to make this method synchronized (and reduce efficiency)?

Comment: `MBeanServerConnection` doesn't have a `close()` method (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html)... can you show us an example?

Comment: I'm calling the close() method on JMXConnector's object (originally returned by JMXConnectionFactory's connect() method)

Answer (score 5):

I think the short answer is that you need to use synchronization and take the performance hit.

Given that JMX calls are RMI/network based, a `synchronized` block would be *very* cheap in comparison.  Any solution that you implement that has a usage counter would suffer from race conditions -- especially considering that JMXConnector most likely has no protection against close/connect race conditions.  For example, someone could be closing the connection at the same time someone else was connecting and the new connection might be closed.

I think you should write a wrapper class (or method) to the connector.  It would:

- Have a connect method that would call `connect()` (only if the usage-counter was 0), call `getMBeanServerConnection()`, and increment the usage-counter and return the connection.
- Have a close method that would decrement the usage-counter and call close if it is 0.
- Be synchronized to avoid the race conditions.

Best of luck.